Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class java.lang.Exception]: {public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
I'm migrating Spring Boot microservice from version 2021.0.9 to 2023.0.1. I have one microservice with shared library for handling exceptions.
Spring Boot microservice:
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
public class CommonControllerAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  private static final String LABEL = "Label";

  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleHystrixBadRequestException(
    .........
    return null;
  }
}

Shared library:
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
public class CommonControllerAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
  
  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(Exception ex) {
    ......
    return ....;
  }
}

Error during boot time:
Error creating bean with name 'handlerExceptionResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception with message: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class java.lang.Exception]: {public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.atlas.mpp.transaction.search.web.rest.SearchControllerAdvice.handleHystrixBadRequestException(java.lang.Exception), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.error.web.handlers.CommonControllerAdvice.handleException(java.lang.Exception)}
.........
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception with message: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class java.lang.Exception]: {public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.microservice.SearchControllerAdvice.handleHystrixBadRequestException(java.lang.Exception), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.lib.web.handlers.CommonControllerAdvice.handleException(java.lang.Exception)}
.......
Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class java.lang.Exception]: {public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.microservice.web.rest.SearchControllerAdvice.handleHystrixBadRequestException(java.lang.Exception), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.lib.web.handlers.CommonControllerAdvice.handleException(java.lang.Exception)}

This code was working fine in version 2021.0.9 but in version 2023.0.1 I get the above error. Looks like there is a restructure in new version. What are the possible ways to solve this?

The error is that your Spring application detects multiple classes that provide @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class) and Spring is telling you that only one can be present, otherwise it confuses Spring as the framework does not know which one to use.
The error specifies that the following method/classes provide handling for @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class):
1.com.microservice.web.rest.SearchControllerAdvice.handleHystrixBadRequestException(java.lang.Exception)

com.lib.web.handlers.CommonControllerAdvice.handleException(java.lang.Exception)

To solve this pick one of your handlers (ideally your common library) and remove the other @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class). Another solution would be to change the handler in SearchControllerAdvice.handleHystrixBadRequestException and provide a more specific class like @ExceptionHandler(AnExceptionSubclassException.class).

Is it possible to override the method into the library?

You could try to make SearchControllerAdvice to inherit CommonControllerAdvice. Then you remove @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class) from the child class, and add @Override instead. But you would be overriding whatever the handling in the library is doing which defeats the purpose of having a common handling.

One more question: Do you know why in version 2021.0.9 I was not getting this issue?

The dependency you point out is for spring cloud but your issue is related to spring core if I am not mistaken. I think you have upgraded something else besides spring cloud because it don’t think it should have worked before. Could it be that you have a parent Pom and the common library got also a bump and the new version includes the exception handler?
